# Making an iOS app to show Standard, Military, and Zulu time all on one screen

Tags: ios

I have been trying to figure out how to make an app where it shows standard, military, and zulu time all on one screen. The code i have now is

```
- (void)UpdateTime {

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatS = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatS setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
_standardTime.text = [dateFormatS stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
[self performSelector:@selector(UpdateTime) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatM = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatM setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
_militaryTime.text = [dateFormatM stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
[self performSelector:@selector(UpdateTime) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatZ = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatZ setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormatZ setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
_zuluTime.text = [dateFormatZ stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
[self performSelector:@selector(UpdateTime) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
}
```

This shows what i want on the app but the only problem is it uses so much memory and after around 10 seconds after the app starts the seconds stop on all the times. Is there a simpler way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UpdateTime` method calls itself 3 times. This means the 1st second it's called once, then a second later it's called 3 times, then a second later it's called 9 times, then a second later it's called 27 times, etc.

Get rid of the first two calls to `performSelector` and just call it once at the end of the method.

Better yet, setup a repeating timer that calls its action every second.

You should also avoid creating the same three `NSDateFormatter` instances each time. Create them once as ivars and reuse them each time.